# Does HTML Canvas integrate well?

Tags: html, canvas, integration

I had this grand scheme to make this cool website with all these bells and whistles, and I decided to use HTML canvas b/c it offers so much flexibility. However, as time wore on, I began to realize that I was just reinventing the wheel, for example manually implementing or integrating:

1. Mouse/Keyboard events
2. User (text) input
3. Simple Animations (ie. fade)
4. Buttons, drop down menus

The first one, especially makes one realize how much we take for granted things like `onmouseover`. I understand what the canvas is for --loosely collected under the umbrella of pixel manipulation-- so I guess to cut this rant short, my question is this: Does anyone else think the canvas does not integrate well with all the other godly goodness of HTML5? Off the top of my head, here are two basic things that would be neat to embed in the canvas (please feel free to correct me if they are already included)

1. Embedding of other websites: For example, If I have a star shape, I want to connect its `onlcick` function to load a web page, then use the `context.beginPath` and `context.clip` functions to make the star 'hollow' so the web site is visible inside the star. This is attainable in the canvas by putting the canvas over the html page (inside a floating frame) and having a transparent background, but what if I want, for example, a grid of 10x10 stars all with their own web site? What if I want to scale the size of each web page?
2. Non rectangular elements/widgets: One thing I tried to tackle with was a circular text editor. This is attainable with the `context.beginPath` and `context.clip` functions, with the `textentry` or `textarea` in the background, however, the signals are caught by the canvas, and not relayed through to the visible, but nonetheless underlying, `textarea` or `textentry` element. It is technically possible to catch each signal, assess it, generate new signals from it, and pass it onto the desired target, but I could not get it to work at all. It would be very useful if there was a way to embed html elements into a canvas shape. [edit] Also, I forgot to mention that one can not shape the actual canvas element. For example if you draw a circle in the middle of the window, the canvas is still a rectangle, and the areas outside of the circle will still occlude underlying content and/or capture user generated events

Comment: Voting to close, as this is not really a clearly answerable question. It appears to be more a vague rant or list of things that HTML5 canvas is not good for. Note that HTML5 Canvas is not meant to replace HTML, but more like a nice way to draw your own `<img>` or video. There's no reason, IMO, to re-implement a `<button>` in a canvas; simply create an HTML button and place it where you like. You might also want to look at SVG if you want a retained-mode graphics API (where things like `mouseover` are handled for you).

Comment: @Phrogz: I tried that approach for implementing a button in the canvas, but it has several problems. One, it occludes the canvas, so you can't have canvas animations on top of the button. Two, bizzare highlights pop up when you double click the canvas (try it here). The button will be highlighted.

Comment: a) That's a reasonable point, that will hopefully be solved when CSS3 `pointer-events:none` allows you to layer another canvas over the button without it catching the mouse clicks, and b) it sounds to me like you're not properly disabling user selection events when you wanted them to be caught.

Comment: @Phrogz: wrt b) I know you can disable the cascade of events by returning false, but my argument is that this calls for a great deal of micromanagement. Take the button, we have to keep track of when we are inside the canvas so we can stop the cascade in case the user double clicks, but then we have to remember to turn it back on when we leave the canvas. This micromanagement is what I dislike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i don't think canvas does not integrate well witch all the other godly goodness of HTML5 (whatever that is)

1. Embedding of other websites... Or i'm not getting your point or this is really a very very strange feature to want.
2. Circular text editor? Embedding HTML Elements inside Canvas?? I'm losing you here...

I suggest you to read the [Canvas specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/) and to look into some libraries like [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to EaselJS

Comment: If anyone reads this, DO NOT USE EASELJS. It is a good attempt to simplify the canvas, but it is so inefficient that it renders the canvas element useless. Here are a series of [tests](https://pukster@github.com/pukster/Easel-scripts.git) which highlight the performance difference. The one with the rollover effect of around 800 boxes works flawlessly in pure Canvas/JS, but is far too slow in EaselJS

Comment: Here is another [link](http://pukster.github.com/Easel-scripts/), that one does not seem to work

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very usefull info, i will look into it.